# javascript array loop to html dom

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am close but cannot figure out how to loop through array of gameboard and print the results to doms container in html. I have been stuck here for a while now.

I need to add the cells into my container by looping over the gameBoard array I made and adding the divs to the DOMs

```js
const game = () => {
    const myTest = () => console.log('test');
    // game board 
    
    return { };
};

var gameBoard = [];
var cell = document.createElement('div');
cell.innerText = "x"
    
    // adds 9 cells to game board
    var createBoard = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            gameBoard.push(cell);
            console.log(cell)
    }
    return gameBoard;
}


createBoard()

var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

container[0].parentElement,appendChild(cell)

for (var i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++){
    container.appendChild(cell[i])
}
```

```css
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

.cell {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
    
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your game board meant to be 3x3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed 2 parts of your code for it to work.

First, I comment out this line since it causes syntax error and the line itself is actually not needed.

```
//container[0].parentElement,appendChild(cell)
```

Second, I changed the line inside this for-loop. The element from `cell` can only exist inside a parent 1 at a time. So, if you need multiple cells like this, you need to clone the node and append them to the container.

```
for (var i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++){
    container[0].appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true))
}
```

See this snippet for the full code with working solution.

```js
const game = () => {
    const myTest = () => console.log('test');
    // game board 
    
    return { };
};

var gameBoard = [];
var cell = document.createElement('div');
cell.innerText = "x"
    
    // adds 9 cells to game board
    var createBoard = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            gameBoard.push(cell);
            console.log(cell)
    }
    return gameBoard;
}


createBoard()

var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");

//container[0].parentElement,appendChild(cell)

for (var i = 0; i < gameBoard.length; i++){
    container[0].appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true))
}
```

```css
.container {
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

.cell {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
    
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch hoy dragon. I just need to study cell.cloneNode(true) , I have never seen this before.